# Filling out input text boxes if they contain a partial word

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm toying around more with Selenium lately, i know pretty much the basics i'm wondering if there is a way to do this:

if input text field contains (partially) the word: "user" then:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input‌[contains('user')]").send_keys("username")
```

So essentially if the input text tag contains the work "user" it's assumed it's a username field, the same would apply to "password" and "email"

I'm not sure if this is even possible, from Googling i can't see anything that stands out, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _...if input text field contains (partially) the word: "user"..._ within which attribute?

Comment: can you post the html on your original post and also your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad approach of populating fields.
You don't know what field what value will accept. Lets take two fields have 'user':

```
<input name='userPassword'/>
<input name'userName'/>
```

In that case, we will have 2 matches and will be really hard to debug or understand what really is happening.

Just follow the normal approach and define the locators using w3c strategies:

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#locator-strategies

p.s. 
In case you wish to struggle with such kind of solution.

You can iterate all elements by tag 'input' and reach the 'attributes' Map.
[image]